# Should ROC and Precision-Recall axes be rotatated to 45%?

Tags: data-visualization

When we see a line plot it is almost always displays a causal relationship of a dependent variable on the y-axis plotted against the independent variable on the x-axis.

However, ROC and P-R curves are totally different. I've been having trouble explaining them and how they are created to to my boss and other people in my department. Do you think that rotating the axes 45 degrees counterclockwise would let people see the charts as abstract objects and make it easier for them to understand the concepts?

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear whether this would help or not. Loy and Hofmann did an experiment examining rotated QQ-plots, and found that people did worse at reading them. If the vertical axis is represents change from a baseline, then it might help.

Comment: I really like the idea of something like a "qq deviation plot"